# Master info Detail info in the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web Form called " Invoice.aspx ". It has a standard toolbar and buttons like 
"***SAVE***", "***CLEAR***" , "***DELETE***" etc..

in the **Invoice.aspx** Page it has **Header** data & **Details** (**grid**) data.

the Header data : " ***Invoice No, date, Customer*** "

the Detail Grid data : *** Charge ID,  Description,  qty,  rate,  amount***

my senario is,

Once I Finish entered the *Header* info and *details* info, (When I Click ***save*** button in the toolbar) I want to save the data into the Databse

Please help me

Thanks

Suhaib

Answer (score 0):

The answer is too specific, maybe you can get what you need here.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms